# What is the equivalent of Python any() and all() functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Python has built in functions `any()` and `all()`, which are applied on a list (array in JavaScript) as following-

- `any()`: Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.
- `all()`: Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

We can create our customized functions for above, but please let me know if there any equivalent built-in functions available in JavaScript.

Comment: [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Only recent releases of Javascript support them, though.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) gives you pure-python equivalents for both functions; they are trivial to translate to JavaScript:

```js
function any(iterable) {
    for (var index = 0; index < iterable.length; index++) {
        if (iterable[index]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and

```js
function all(iterable) {
    for (var index = 0; index < iterable.length; index++) {
        if (!iterable[index]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Recent browser versions (implementing ECMAScript 5.1, Firefox 1.5+, Chrome, Edge 12+ and IE 9) have native support in the form of [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every); these take a callback that determines if something is 'true' or not:

```js
some_array.some((elem) => !!elem );
some_array.every((elem) => !!elem );
```

The Mozilla documentation I linked to has polyfills included to recreate these two methods in other JS implementations.

Answer (score 5):

You can use lodash.

`lodash.every` is equivalent to `all`

`lodash.some` is equivalent to `any`

Comment: `some` and `every` is built in, don't need a third party lib for this.

Answer (score 3):

Build-in function `some` is equivalent to any I suppose.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const even = function(element) {
  // checks whether an element is even
  return element % 2 === 0;
};

console.log(array.some(even));
// expected output: true
```

You can read more in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)