# image scraping pointing each url to directory using php

Tags: php

I have the code for image scraping but what I am trying to fix here are a few things:

1. replace this `$the_site = "url";` with my input `type="text"`
   so instead of putting url on the code I want to put the url on my input.
2. I want to make multiple folder and links, instead of putting same code like 5 times on the page I want to to point each url to a directory.

My code is about downloading images from pages and save them to folder so I want to put all inside one php tags

here's my code

```
<?php
    $the_site = "url";
    $the_tag = "div"; #
    $the_class = "slides";

    $html = file_get_contents($the_site);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//'.$the_tag.'[contains(@id,"'.$the_class.'")]/img') as $item) {

        $img_src = $item->getAttribute('src');
        //print $img_src."\n"; Ignore This
        //copy($img_src,'C:\xampp\htdocs\grabIMG\download'); Ignore This
        $img_name = end(explode("/",$img_src));
        echo $img_name.' has downloaded<br />';
        $img_content = file_get_contents($img_src);
        $fp = fopen(" folder/".$img_name,"w");
        fwrite($fp,$img_content);
        fclose($fp);

    }
?>
```

i been posting this code like 5 times in the page, each time opening new php tags but i get this error and excution won't be completed

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grabIMG\index.php on line 106